# Appium error code 253 when try to connect my real device

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

So i have `iPhone 8` with the latest version (12.2) and `MAC + Xcode` (also latest versions)

I follow [this tutorial][1] and after insert this `Appium desired capabilities`:

```
{
  "app": "/Users/myUser/Documents/ipa_files/igrocket_v85.0_T3.3.2.ipa",
  "udid": "3b5c144433dacabd34311251d33bd2afa661be47",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 8",
  "platformVersion": "12.2",
  "noReset": true
}'
```

I got this `error`:

> iOS-deploy could not install application exited with code 253

**Appium log**

```
**[XCUITest] Error: Could not install app: 'Command 'ios-deploy --id 3b5c144433dacabd74d93251d33bd2afa661be47 --bundle /var/folders/b9/sq2txlwd7b33njkgq7qgffhw0000gn/T/2019229-1728-as7h53.ceh0m/Payload/Instagram.app' exited with code 253'
[XCUITest]     at IOSDeploy.install (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/ios-deploy.js:40:13)
[XCUITest]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1553871674896 (18:01:14 GMT+0300 (IDT))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not install app: 'Command 'ios-deploy --id 3b5c144433dacabd34311251d33bd2afa661be47--bundle /var/folders/b9/sq2txlwd7b33njkgq7qgffhw0000gn/T/2019229-1728-as7h53.ceh0m/Payload/Instagram.app' exited with code 253'
[MJSONWP]     at IOSDeploy.install (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/ios-deploy.js:40:13)
[MJSONWP]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 44559 ms - 355
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {}
[HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain**
```

What could cause this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Error 253 occurs when your application has not been code signed properly. Look in the build settings and associate your Developer Certificate with the Code Signing section of the application under test. Note that both the application being tested AND the Appium XCUITEST project must both be signed with the same certificate to be able to interact with, and thus automate, testing of your application.

**Edit:** Unfortunately, I no longer have access to a Mac, and thus I can best link you to how to do this.

Open the projects in XCode, and then go to the project settings as seen here:

Image url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH6gN.jpg
[image: This is the code signing area of XCode]

[Here is information on what this all means and how to do it](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/what-is-a-provisioning-profile-in-ios-77987a7c54c2)

**Edit #2:** I'm fairly confident that what you are trying to do is impossible. Let me know if you are employee of Instagram. But it doesn't seem like you are. And you are trying to automate an Instagram application that you do not own; on apple devices.

Apple security does not allow this. You MUST sign both the WebDriverAgent and application under test with the same developer certificate. It is impossible to use XCUITest API's without the signed certificates that prove you are the owner and purveyor of the app being tested.

Apple is extremely restrictive about this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can i do this ?

Comment: Maybe you want me to post some photos from the project to understand what is wrong ? (is yes please tell me what)

Comment: Added a picture above along with a tutorial. If you take a screenshot of the same area of your XCode, that might help. Although the tutorial and info above may get you where you need to go on their own too.

Comment: This pic is very very small, do you have it in bigger size ?

Comment: Im not sure why StackOverflow sized it like that. But I added the url directly https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH6gN.jpg

Comment: Just to verify, that certificate is an identical certificate to the one used to sign the app that you are testing?

Comment: I really dont know, how can i check it ?

Comment: Open up the non compiled project for the application you are testing. Essentially, do exactly what you need before in the screenshot you posted, but with the app you are testing.

Comment: My device did not have the application (instagram) installed on it, so after installed and try again got new error, see my edit

Comment: I've added a second edit to the post. What you are suggesting is impossible. Unless you are an employee of Instagram. If you are, then let me know. Otherwise, this is impossible.

Comment: No i am not Instagram employee, so how can i connect to my iphone and automate app ? (and it does not matter what app)

Comment: You cannot automate ANY application that you do NOT own on an Apple device. Apple and XCUItest will not allow it. If you want to automate an app that you do own, we can assist. Unfortunately, what you are asking above is not possible.

Comment: But appium allow to connect real device and start app/install app

Comment: Appium will load an application onto the device, but if the security certificates do not match between Appium and the application under test, iOS and XCUITest will refuse to open a port that would allow the app and appium to communicate over.

Comment: So how can i fix it ?

Comment: You cannot fix it. What you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: And what about install application from app file like apk ?

Comment: It may be possible from Android with an apk. Give it a try, and if you have any problems with it on an Android device with an apk, create another question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: And what about the tutorial from this post ? it show how to connect the devoce, why i got this error code 253 ?

Comment: @falukky The tutorial will not help you. I added that before you said that the application was Instagram. Because you do not own the application, everything you were trying to do is impossible. You cannot do this with iOS devices.

Comment: No problem. Good luck.